# apache rewrite static url to dynamic

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm try to rewrite my url

http://www.domain.com/live/randomword

it should go rewrite to

http://www.domain.com/live/?cat=randomword

here are my tests:

```
RewriteRule ^live/(.*)$ /live/?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^live/(.*)$ live/?cat=$1
```

and all i have in the htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Comment: Do you want redirect the user to the other page, or rewrite it silently? If you want to rewrite it silently you should probably rewrite it to a PHP page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to add a `RewriteBase /` to your .htaccess and to suffix your rule with a [L] to say it's last rewrite rule ending with something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^live/(.*)$ live/index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

If this still doesn't work be sure to check that mod_rewrite is enabled

also you can do a [R,L] instead of [L] to see the redirection in the url and so have more info on what's going own.

hope this help

Comment: what happen when you replace [L] by [R,L] ? Does it perform a redirect? If yes what is the redirected url, if not it's probably that mod_rewrite isn't enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Have this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^live/(.*)$ /live/?cat=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

in rewrite rule the file name or extension in missing?

write rule like,

RewriteRule ^live/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /viewcategory.php?cat=$1